# Electronics to select every third pulse from Ti-sapphire laser

Tags: digital-logic, adc, photodiode, high-frequency

I'm currently building an optical imaging system and have run into some difficulty. The optical source is a Ti-sapphire laser which outputs pulses at 80 MHz and I'm using a photomultipler tube as a detector. I would like to trigger my sampling based on every third pulse from the Ti-sapphire (in other words I would like to sample at 80/3 MHz). I have already setup a fast photodiode that can detect each pulse. Is there a way I can easily pick off every third pulse?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a photodiode detector that can output a digital 1 or 0 on every pulse then creating a trigger that outputs on every 3rd pulse is not that hard.

Make a state machine that essentially counts to 3 and then resets.

Let there be a clock signal that is the output of your photodiode detector.
Let there be a 2 bit state variable that counts the pulses (lets call it C).
Let there be a trigger output.  Lets call it T.

An HDL description for the state machine would look like...


`if rising_edge(clock) then
    if C = "00" then C <= "01";
    elsif C = "01" then C <= "10";
    else C <= "00";
end if;
T <= C = 00;`


You could of course synthesize that HDL code on a CPLD directly.  Alternatively you could use a few 74-series logic chips to implement the logic.

C(0) <= C(0) NOR C(1)
C(1) <= (C(0) NOR C(0)) NOR C(1)

T = C(0) NOR C(1)

So you would need a quad NOR gate, and two D-Flip-Flops.

Also, as some have suggested, you could use the pulse detector to clock a 3 stage shift register arranged in a circle.  Your trigger would be the output of one of the three register stages.

The shift register would need to be preloaded with the value "100".  After the first pulse the value would shift to "010", after the second "001", and then after the third it would go back to "100".  So you would have a 1 on your trigger every third pulse.

Comment: That's "elsif" not "else if" and you need another "then" (but a counter would be simpler)

Comment: Instead of nands and nors, you could also preload a three bit cyclic shift register with 0 0 1 and use the pulses to clock it, and read out the highest bit.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I agree, the shift register could also work, and could potentially support higher clock rates.

Comment: @Brian Drummond Thanks for the syntax checking.  I fixed it.

Comment: Hi, I wouldn't recommend a state machine to anybody to do a fixed sequence, particularly a sequence so tiny. As others have suggested, a ring counter or a binary counter is simpler and therefore faster and better. An FSM may reduce to similar here but it's not a good road to start from

Comment: @  TonyM I agree with respect to using the shift register based counter provided that there is some other logic to pre-load it.  A binary counter on the other hand tends to naturally wrap on a power of two.  Since he wanted to reset every third pulse a binary counter wasn't a natural choice since one would have had to build additional logic to trigger the reset on a compare for every third count (which is essentially what the state machine does).

Comment: The recirculating shift register will work and be fast, but you really need to detect the disallowed states and use this to re-initialize if they occur.  Otherwise, a random noise glitch can put the register into a completely unusable state.  You have three valid states, and five invalid ones.